# Joomla Category Home Pages

Tags: joomla2.5, categories

Is there any way in Joomla2.5 to create Home/Landing Pages (ie. "default") pages for each category.
For example, I would like the user to be able to go to www.somejoomlasite.com/category1 and see a default home page for category1, and a different home page for category2 and so on.  Is there any way to achieve this?  Could I create an article under each category and set it's alias as index?  or will I get an error about having duplicate aliases (even though they are under different categories)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I need to provide further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias has to be unique within a category. So you should be fine using the same alias in different categories.

You should be able to achieve a structure like you described with menu items for each category. And of course SEF needs to be turned on with rewrite enabled.
The menu items don't need to be visible on the page, you can also create a "hidden" menu. Just don't show the accompagning menu module.
These menu items can be anything: a category list of the articles, an article itself, a featured list of articles in a category or whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying that now, will let you know how it goes!